# Closure Compiler Error: JSC_NOT_A_CONSTRUCTOR

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-closure-compiler

I was playing around with closure compiler and put in this code:

```
var obj = (function() {
  function H(a) {
    this.a = a
  }
  var h = new H(1);
  h.b=1
  return h
})();
```

I wanted to see if it would convert it to this:

```
var obj = (function() {
  function H(a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = 1
  }
  var h = new H(1);
  return h;
})();
```

But instead I got this error
`JSC_NOT_A_CONSTRUCTOR: cannot instantiate non-constructor at line 6 character 8
var h = new H(1);`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell CC that the function is a constructor via [`@constructor`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler?hl=de):

```
/**
 * Makes an H.
 * @constructor
 */
function H() {
  ...
}
```